# Select Attributes From Rails Nested Includes Association With ActiveModelSerializer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, active-model-serializers

So i've been struggling with this for a few hours and im hoping someone can help.

I have a 3 level relationship, List, Page & App.
A List has_many Pages 
A Page belongs_to List and can optionally belongs_to an App.
App has_many Pages

With a query like this

`@account.lists.includes(pages: :app)`

Everything works fine,  I have no N+1 queries, and its all being eager loaded correctly

Eg

```
List Load (3.0ms)  SELECT `lists`.* FROM `rotations` WHERE `lists`.`account_id` = 1
Page Load (2.5ms)  SELECT `pages`.* FROM `pages` WHERE `pages`.`list_id` IN (13, 17, 18)
App Load (2.0ms)  SELECT `apps`.* FROM `apps` WHERE `apps`.`id` IN (6, 9, 15)
```

My problem is that all these statements are `SELECT * FROM` although the Apps records in particular are quite heavy.  There can be entire HTML documents in a column named "content"

I really need to be able to only `SELECT apps.id, apps.name FROM`apps ....`. So im not loading these full objects into memory only just discard it all a moment later when I render only the ID and names.

I would perform this manually, although I can't seem to get this working with ActiveModelSerializers.

My serializers are pretty standard.  A List that has_many :pages and a page that belongs_to :app.

How can I only pull select attributes from one of my nested associations? Im pretty sure I can use `joins()` but im not sure how that works with my serializers?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.. trying to test this on an app with similar associations. I think something like this might work:

```
@account.lists.includes(pages: :app).pluck("apps.id", "apps.name")
```

This will do a LEFT OUTER JOIN on the associations.

```
@account.lists.joins(pages: :app).pluck("apps.id", "apps.name")
```

will do INNER JOINS. Not sure what you are looking for exactly without a lot more info on your data structures and example output.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so that kind of works, but I have to specify every field for all tables, although then my ActiveModelSerializer doesn't work, it doesn't recognize the objects.   You know of any way to make that work?

Comment: it also appears that when plucking everything, the object comes back flat.  As in no nesting, which is possible why AMS breaks trying to render relations